# How to remove Add to cart warning message without size color selection?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, messages, notification

I have to remove the `You need to choose options for your item.` on `Add to cart` button when I don't select any color or size.
I don't want to show this as a global message.

I found that `Add to cart` is an ajax call . But I am not able to debug how this `You need to choose options for your item.` is getting set and 
**how can I remove it?**

Answer (score 0):

Add below code before 
this line: **`$this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);`**
in

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php

```
if(!$product->hasOptionsValidationFail()){
    $redirectUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
    $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($redirectUrl);
    return $this->goBack($redirectUrl);
}
```

Please override this controller do not change in core.

Comment: There is no such method hasOptionsValidationFail() in /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php

Comment: It's working. I have tried and then answer. You'll find this method in /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php 383. Please check.